# Extension methods for Identity Controllers in ASP.Net Core 2.2 App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

In my older MVC app I had some extension methods like the one below

```
 public static string ChangePasswordCallbackLink(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, string appUserId, string parameter)
 {
     return urlHelper.Action(
            action: nameof(AccountController.ChangePassword),
            controller: "Account",
            values: new { appUserId, parameter}
            );
 }
```

Since there is no longer an account controller (something I still don't understand in Core) when you scaffold out the identity pages in the default Asp.Net Core 2.2 Web Application, how does one go about creating this type of extension?

Comment: Use extension method to create link like :https://localhost:xxxxxx/Identity/Account/Manage/ChangePassword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AccountController is just a scaffolded class containing basic logic for user account management, you can create it easily on your own. 
I did HomeController containing ChangePassword action method and HomePage with predefined parameters for the link:

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string ChangePasswordCallbackLink(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, string appUserId, string parameter)
        {
            return urlHelper.Action(
                action: nameof(HomeController.ChangePassword),
                controller: "Home",
                values: new { appUserId, parameter }
            );
        }
    }
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult ChangePassword(string appUserId, string parameter)
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var link = Url.ChangePasswordCallbackLink("123", "qwerty");
            return View(model: link);
        }
    }
```

Written extension method still works well